# How to get substring after last occurrence of character in string: Swift IOS

Tags: string, swift

Basically, I want to make a program where if you start typing a name, the app will recognize it from the database and fill in the name for you. To do this, if a person types a comma after finishing a name, the app will start recording what the next name is. If it matches as a substring of one of the names in the database, it will fill it in for the user. The issue is that I need to get what part of the name has been filled out so far after the last occurrence of the comma character in the textField string, but I don't know how. For example:
User types: "Daniel, Joh"
And the app fills in John for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want the characters after the last comma, you could use a regular expression:

```
let string = "Hamilton, A"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ",\\s*(\\S[^,]*)$")
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: string.nsRange), let result = string[match.range(at: 1)] {
    // use `result` here
}
```

Where, in Swift 4:

```
extension String {

    /// An `NSRange` that represents the full range of the string.

    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return NSRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, in: self)
    }

    /// Substring from `NSRange`
    ///
    /// - Parameter nsRange: `NSRange` within the string.
    /// - Returns: `Substring` with the given `NSRange`, or `nil` if the range can't be converted.

    subscript(nsRange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
            .flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the regex solution also work if there are more than 2 names on the list?

Comment: Sorry I'm just asking because it says firstMatchInString not last. Thanks

Comment: OK, I understand the confusion. But if you look at my regex string, the last character is a `$`, which says "match for the end of the string". Thus, you'll get only one match, the one at the end (if any). I only use `firstMatchInString` because, since we're only getting the last one, there's no need to enumerate through, but rather just grab the "first" match at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to Rob. We can even extend his String extension by including the full answer to the initial question, with any Character:

```
extension String {

func substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(_ char: Character) -> String {

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\(char)\\s*(\\S[^\(char)]*)$")
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, range: self.nsRange), let result = self[match.range(at: 1)] {
        return String(result)
    }
    return ""
}

// ... Rob's String extension 

}
```

So we just need to call:

```
let subStringAfterLastComma = "Hamilton, A".substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(",")
```

Comment: Not working any more: `Value of type 'String' has no member 'nsRange'`

Comment: @PaulSpiesberger you need to include rob's extension too, then it will work

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with `range(of` and options `regularExpression` and `backwards`.

It searches for a comma followed by an optional whitespace character.

```
extension String {
    var subStringAfterLastComma : String {
        guard let subrange = self.range(of: ",\\s?", options: [.regularExpression, .backwards]) else { return self }
        return String(self[subrange.upperBound...])
    }
}

let string1 = "Dan".subStringAfterLastComma // "Dan"
let string2 = "Daniel, Joh".subStringAfterLastComma // "Joh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rob and Thierry G.

```
extension String {
    
    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return Foundation.NSRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, in: self)
    }
    
    subscript(nsRange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
            .flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
    
    func substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(_ char: Character) -> String {
        
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\(char)\\s*(\\S[^\(char)]*)$")
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, range: self.nsRange), let result = self[match.range(at: 1)] {
            return String(result)
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

we can use like this

```
let subStringAfterLastComma = "Hamilton, A".substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(",")
```