# Cut a String from start position to end position with swift 3

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string

I have Strings with the form string \ string example

```
"some sting with random length\233"
```

I want to deletes the last `\` and get the value after it, so the result will be

```
"some sting with random length"
"233"
```

I tried this code but it's not working

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\s*(\\S[^,]*)$")
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: string.nsRange) {
    let result = string.substring(with: match.rangeAt(1))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you have `"some sting with random length\\233"`? A backslash must be doubled in a string literal to represent a single literal backslash.

Comment: No, only one \. I tried exactly the same solution that you marked and its not working, thats why I posted the question

Comment: The thing is that `\2` is actually `2`. Your *string* does not contain a backslash, thus there is nothing to split or match. Again, a literal ``\`` should be defined with ``\\`` inside a Swift string literal. That is all I can say here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not correctly adapt the pattern from [How to get substring after last occurrence of character in string: Swift IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905301/how-to-get-substring-after-last-occurrence-of-character-in-string-swift-ios/36905647#36905647) to your case. *Both* instances of the comma must be replaced by a backslash,
and that must be "double-escaped":

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\\\\s*(\\S[^\\\\]*)$")
```

(once be interpreted as a literal backslash in the regex pattern, and
once more in the definition of a Swift string literal).

*However,* a simpler solution is to find the last occurrence of the
backslash and extract the suffix from that position:

```
let string = "some sting with random length\\233"
let separator = "\\" // A single(!) backslash

if let r = string.range(of: separator, options: .backwards) {
    let prefix = string.substring(to: r.lowerBound)
    let suffix = string.substring(from: r.upperBound)

    print(prefix)  // some sting with random length
    print(suffix)  // 233
}
```

**Update for Swift 4:**

```
if let r = string.range(of: separator, options: .backwards) {
    let prefix = string[..<r.lowerBound]
    let suffix = string[r.upperBound...]

    print(prefix)  // some sting with random length
    print(suffix)  // 233
}
```

`prefix` and `suffix` are a `String.SubSequence`, which can be used
in many places instead of a `String`. If necessary, create a *real*
string:

```
    let prefix = String(string[..<r.lowerBound])
    let suffix = String(string[r.upperBound...])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with regex, but I think this solution is better:

```
yourString.components(separatedBy: "\\").last!
```

It splits the string with `\` as the separator and gets the last split.